# error on last done preventing further processing in bash

Tags: bash

The below `bash` seems to error on the last `done`.  What is the correct syntax as I can not seem to figure it out without created more errors.  There are some additional processes after that will not run because an error is thrown currently.  Thank you :).

**error**

```
/home/cmccabe/Desktop/loop.sh: line 79: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
/home/cmccabe/Desktop/loop.sh: line 79: `done >> "$logfile"'
```

**bash**

```
logfile=/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/6-2-2016/process.log
for file in /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/6-2-2016/vcf/overall/stats/*.vcf ; do
 echo "Start annovar creation: $(date) - file: $file"
 echo ${file##*/} >> /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/annovar/target.txt
cp /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/6-2-2016/vcf/overall/stats/*.vcf /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/annovar
 echo "End annovar file creation: $(date) - file: $file"
done

logfile=/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/6-2-2016/process.log
cd "/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/annovar"
$( perl -ne 'chomp; system ("perl table_annovar.pl -vcfinput $_ humandb/ -buildver hg19 -arg '-hgvs',,,,,,,,,, -remove -protocol IDP.refGene,avsnp147,popfreq_all_20150413,spidex,ljb26_sift,ljb26_pp2hdiv,ljb26_pp2hvar,ljb26_lrt,ljb26_mt,ljb26_ma,clinvar_20160302 -operation g,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f")' < target.txt )
mv /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/annovar/*multianno.txt /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/6-2-2016/vcf/overall/annovar
  echo "End annovar annotation creation: $(date) - file: $file"
done >> "$logfile"
```

Comment: By virtue of surrounding it with `$( )`, you're parsing and running the `stdout` from your `perl` script as a command. Is that really what you want? (Actually, not even fully parsing; string-splitting and glob expansion only).

Comment: Runnning perl to shell out to run another long perl command is somewhat horrifying. Also, you appear to be copying every file in the stats dir *twice*, once for each file itself. Are you sure you don't just want `cp "$f" /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/annovar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `>>` at the `echo` line, as such. The `done` is also redundant; there's no loop to close:

```
logfile=/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/6-2-2016/process.log
cd "/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/annovar"
$( perl -ne 'chomp; system ("perl table_annovar.pl -vcfinput $_ humandb/ -buildver hg19 -arg '-hgvs',,,,,,,,,, -remove -protocol IDP.refGene,avsnp147,popfreq_all_20150413,spidex,ljb26_sift,ljb26_pp2hdiv,ljb26_pp2hvar,ljb26_lrt,ljb26_mt,ljb26_ma,clinvar_20160302 -operation g,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f")' < target.txt )
mv /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/annovar/*multianno.txt /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/6-2-2016/vcf/overall/annovar
  # See here
echo "End annovar annotation creation: $(date) - file: $file" >> "$logfile"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and explanation :)

Comment: @Chris No worries - remember to accept the answer when you can :)

Comment: @ sorry @Nick Bull I had to wait until now... thanks again :)